# Table is not deleting when it's called?

Tags: sql-server-2008, coldfusion

I have a link where I click on it it goes to

```
isDefined("url.ghd_id")
```

and when i click on it its not deleting a specific table 'gh_answers', but all the other
tables and code I have it runs it correctly.I don't get any errors it just not deleting the records
from the table. I have done some testing below in the code and in the test_table it does delete the record.

What could be going on wrong? If its deleting the test_table it should be able to do the other table.

What I end up doing is running the query on the sql server.

```
<cfoutput query="GetNextMonth" maxrows="1">
        <p>&nbsp;</p><p>Do you want to <a href="file.cfm?ghd_id=#ghd_id#"><strong>test #ghd_yearmonth# due #ghd_duedate#</strong></a>?</p>
</cfoutput>

<cfif isDefined("url.ghd_id")>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
console.log('Testing console 123');
</script>
    <h2> testting</h2>
    <cfquery datasource="Intranet" name="testing123">
    delete from test_table
    </cfquery>
    <!--- this table is not deleting========================= --->
    <cfquery datasource ="Intranet" name="ResetAnswers">
        DELETE FROM gh_answers
    </cfquery>

</cfif>
```

I have try  insert into and it also didn't work.In conclusion insert into, and delete and not working for this specific table,everything else is working.

Comment: im not trying to delete a single record , all the records i want to delete but its not even running that query

Comment: Does the testting header appear on your web page?

Comment: What database are you using? Change the name attribute to result and dump that out to the screen.

Comment: @matt sql, i change the name attribute and i get recordcount=17 looks good to me

Comment: Do what makes you think the code isn't running? That's proof it did run.

Comment: @matt it didnt run because it doesnt delete the table records

Comment: If it shows a recordCount in the result I've never ran into an instance where that was wrong.

Comment: What are you looking at that makes you think the records were not deleted?

Comment: @dan with the code above im doing it for testing, in my 'real' code when i click on the link it runs all the other queries, which have update and insert into, but it doesnt run the delete, how do i know? i check the table in sql server.

Comment: Try `try catch`. Maybe, the user account under which you are running the query doesn't have `Delete` permission.

Comment: In your real code, put a select count(*) from gh_answers and dump the results before and after the delete query.  If you see different results in the dumps, the query ran and records were inserted afterwards.  If you don't see the dumps at all, the isDefined() you were checking returned false.

Comment: @GauravS, if there was a permissions problem, there would be an error on the page.

Comment: Try adding your code to a try catch to find the error. I have made a gist here. https://gist.github.com/wkerswell/4276558b7c1a73842c39

Comment: super late but I have try all this options and still have same problem